# Why I get the error trying to lift up props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling, react-props, setstate

Here I have the state, and I am trying to pass them into child component SearchBar

**App Component (parent component)**

```
  // not related code ...

  // search
  const { search, setSearch } = useState("");

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };
  
  // not related code ...

  return (
    <ContextProviders
      // not related code ...
    >
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <SearchBar search={search} handleSearch={(e) => handleSearch(e)} />
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </ContextProviders>
  );
}
```

Into SearchBar when I am typing something in order to trigger setState it shows up an error:

**SearchBar (child component)**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function SearchBar(props) {
  // not related code ...

  console.log(props);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="search"
          value={props.search}
          onChange={props.handleSearch}
          // not related code ...
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I need to get the value from the input field in the search component(child) into App component(parent), I try to pass a function which sets state into App, but it doesn't work, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: setSearch is not a function at handleSearch

Does anyone see the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize your state as:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
```

And pass the `handleSearch` function like this:

```
<SearchBar search={search} handleSearch={handleSearch} />
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed the mistake)

Answer (score 0):

why did you pass the anonymous arrow function in handleSearch? you just need to point  handleSearch function. There is no need to call it.

Comment: I did it, I got a different error :

Comment: `<SearchBar search={search} handleSearch={handleSearch} />`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: setSearch is not a function at handleSearch`

Comment: I think the problem is I wrapped search and setSearch in an object instead of an array. That's ridiculous ))

Comment: Ohh lol yeah got it it's because of ur useState sorry I didn't notice it earlier